# How to delimit the length in axis.line.x theme for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to delimited the length of the axis.line.x of a ggplot2 theme.
I trying to plot a phylogenetic tree, but I will use mtcars as example to generate geom_point plot, but the problem is the same.

```
data("mtcars")
head(mtcars, 3)
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

I only want the x line, so

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    theme(axis.line.x = element_line())
```

My question is, if I want the axis.line.x just to be plot from 2 to ends in 5 (the rest of the plot must be equal), how could I adjust the length ?, in the image I indicate the line that I want to avoid.

[image]

ggtree plot

is the same problem with ggtree:

```
tree <- read.tree(text= paste("(Organism1.006G249400.1:0.03977,", 
                              "(Organism2.022118m:0.01337,(Organism3.J34265.1:0.00284,",
                              "Organism4.G02633.1:0.00468)0.51:0.0104):0.02469);"))
```

convert to ggtree (its work with ggplot2 format/structure )

```
p <- ggtree(tree) + geom_tiplab()

p + theme(axis.line.x = element_line(), axis.text.x = element_text())
```

I want to avoid the axis.line.x before 0 and after of 0.04

Any suggestion ??

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("segment", x = 2, xend = 5, y = -Inf, yend = -Inf) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_blank())
```

[image]